Problem at cropping raster data using spatVector
I’d have a very basic question to ask, please. I have to crop a number of MODIS LAI raster using a SpatVector. Using the code below, the cropped raster and the SpatVector do not align so I guess that the cropping is not executed properly. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.
library(terra)
library(geodata)

#get spatVector
es <- geodata::gadm(country="ESP", level=1, path=".")
catal <- es[es$NAME_1 == "Cataluña", ]

#get MODIS data
modis <- terra::rast("see link below")
modis <- modis*0.1
# terra::plot(modis)

modis_crs <- terra::crs(modis) #get crs of MODIS data
catal_2 <- terra::project(catal, modis_crs) #give the spatVector the same crs as MODIS
# terra::crs(catal_2)==terra::crs(modis) #check if the two crs are the same
modis_cr <- terra::crop(modis, catal_2) #crop (here without mask)
terra::plot(modis_cr) #plot cropped MODIS data
terra::plot(catal_2, add=TRUE, lwd=2) #plot spatVector with the MODIS crs

A MODIS LAI raster to run this example is available here <- link removed
This is what I get, the two files do not align (ignore the colour of the raster):

I tried to change the crs of MODIS data rather than the crs of the spatVector, I tried with different options of extent, align, or snap. I tried to play a bit with the sf library and read quite a few similar questions.

It seems like the crs definition of your raster is not correct. Overriding this by the proj4string below results in expected positioning:
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.71
library(geodata)

# get data
es <- geodata::gadm(country="ESP", level=1, path=".")
catal <- es[es$NAME_1 == "Cataluña", ] 

# read modis
modis <- terra::rast("cropmodis.tif")

# replace modis crs
terra::crs(modis) <- "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs"

# reproject vector
modis_crs <- terra::crs(modis)
catal_2 <- terra::project(catal, modis_crs)

# crop
modis_cr <- terra::crop(modis, catal_2)

# inspect
terra::plot(modis_cr)
terra::plot(catal_2, add = TRUE)


Note:
The crs definition comes from a random MODIS dataset downloaded from EarthExplorer:
terra::rast("MOD11A2.A2024089.h18v04.061.2024099144843.hdf") |> terra::crs(proj = TRUE)
#> [1] "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs"


@Chris: I'd say this is just a wrong crs definition and would not expect this to be about the type (since we know nothing about raster pre-processing performed). But this seems to be some merge operation in order to cover the area of Spain from individual tiles and format conversion since MODIS data does not come as GeoTIFF, afaik, at least. terra::crs(modis, proj = TRUE) returns "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" by the way.

@Chris: Not necessarily, but characters are limited here to post a WKT2 definition ;-)

This is making ?terra::crs interesting reading in the context of this presented problem. Does the terra::crs atriculation admit using wkt, degraded as it currently is. Something to play around with.

Fantastic, that solved the problem. Thanks a lot. These MODIS LAI data were downloaded from Google Earth Engine, and I therefore assume that GEE sort of lost the correct crs information while merging the tiles to cover Spain. Many thanks again.

@Chris: At least WKT2 seems to be the default crs representation when using terra::crs(), despite the detailed note in ?terra::crs.

Well, if default, I'd describe it as a reluctant default : proceed with caution. I think your and @Fran surmise about GEE processing to merged tile(s) is likely culprit. As to proj vs WKT2, they appear to be independent i.e. a +proj isn't derived from elements of W as the GEE WKT2 has ellipsoid 6378137,298.257223563 that doesn't get pulled into a +R as your Earth Explorer, just the +datum. Well, we'll all know for future GEE questions.
